# Why global has type "typeof globalThis" in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, types

We access different global objects depending on the runtime environment.

`window` - for the browser

`global` - for nodeJs

`globalThis` - for all environments

But for some reason typescript defines global as `typeof globalThis`.
So I can write

```
global.localStorage
```

and not get typescript error.

It looks weird, why was it done that way?

Comment: It is not?? from source  `declare var global: NodeJS.Global;` have you installed the @types/node package?

Comment: Would you be able to point out the source that defines localStorage on NodeJS.Global?

Comment: @Salketer Yes, I have this package and the type is `declare var global: typeof globalThis;` in `globals.global.d.ts`

Comment: Which package is that? Could you give me the name, version and the filepath to that declaration?

Comment: @Salketer package - `"@types/node": "^16.11.6"` 
path - `/node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/globals.global.d.ts`

Comment: Ah, yikes Sorry I had an old version installed! While I can see it now being of type globalThis, typescript does not hint me with localStorage... I guess you'll need someone more expert.